# Import JSON feed to Wordpress

Tags: json

We have received a URL which is a JSON file apparently:

```
http://www.domain.com/tools/export-json/?destination=hawaii
```

I am completely clueless when it comes to JSON and Wordpress.

Anybody know where to start?

We will need to create individual posts from this JSON file I presume..

Comment: There are some PHP native function like `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. [json_decode](http://us.php.net//manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the JSON into an array.

   ```
   $slices = json_decode(file_get_contents('yourJSONFile.json'),true);
   ```
2. Loop into the data

   ```
   if ($slices) { 
      foreach ($slices as $slice) {
         $title = $slice[1];
         // insert more logic here
     }
   }
   ```
3. Create a post programmatically by using [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).

   ```
   // Create post object
   $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    =>  $title,
        'post_content'  => 'This is my content',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_category' => array(8,39)
   );

   // Insert the post into the database and return the new post ID
   $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post, true );
   if ( is_wp_error( $post_id ) ) {
        // error handling....
   }
   ```

More details in this tutorial: http://tommcfarlin.com/programmatically-create-a-post-in-wordpress/

Comment: Please try to include at least summary of information from URL into answer. Links tend to rot, making answers crippled.

Comment: ok thanks for this - it is useful info - if you are aware of any relevant wordpress plugins that would be great too..

Comment: This solution works but is giving me load time error. Is there a faster way for 1000s of posts?